# mysql_real_escape_string - login script

Tags: php, html

I am currently upgrading code for a friends website and have encountered a problem with the login script. I'm trying to prevent SQL Injection by using `mysql_real_escape_string()`. `mysql_escape_string()` works fine but `mysql_real_escape_string()` doesn't. This is what I've got:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $db_link = db_connect("project");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username' AND password = password('$password')";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($numrows == 1)
    {
        RedirectToURL("home.php");
    }
    else
    {
        login_page("Invalid login! Try again");
    }   
}
else
{
    login_page("");
}
```

Comment: maybe this could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: move them to occur after the db connection call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to use mysql_real_escape_string you have to be logged in to the database.
If you are not logged in, then use mysql_escape_string.

Answer (score 2):

As @MichaelBerkowski said in your comment, move the `mysql_real_escape_string()` calls past your connection command:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $db_link = db_connect("project");

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username' AND password = password('$password')";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($numrows == 1)
    {
        RedirectToURL("home.php");
    }
    else
    {
        login_page("Invalid login! Try again");
    }   
}
else
{
    login_page("");
}
```

The reason, as told above, is [`that mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) depends on your mysql connection to work